# How to get json_encode() to work with ISO-8859-1 (åäö)

Tags: php, json, iso-8859-1

`json_encode()` wont work for me when I'm using åäö. Why? And how can I get it to work?

The `php`:

```
echo json_encode($arr);
```

The `javascript`:

```
var theResponse = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);
```

When I `alert()` the response, and the response contains å, ä or ö, the response is = `NULL`

Please, help me out...

Comment: What output are you getting?  Which JSON library are you using?

Comment: The output is `NULL` if it contains å, ä or ö. The JSON library is http://www.JSON.org/json2.js

Comment: What PHP version are you using? I believe early versions of `json_encode()` only handled UTF-8 strings properly. Try `utf8_encode`-ing the the string before encoding and see if that works.

Comment: PHP version is 5.something. Have tried `utf8_encode` but it did not work for me.

Comment: Actually `utf8_encode` did work :) !!! Happy again.

Comment: @gunderwonder. If you want cred for your answer, make you comment to an answer...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Greg mentioned, I had to encode åäö to `UTF-8`. But I did't use iconv or mbstring. When I `utf8_encode()` all values before putting the values to the `array` the problem was solved.

Comment: I'm facing a similar problem, where I've got an associative array which needs to be encoded. I've tried `array_walk_recursive()` with `if(is_string($input)) { return utf_encode($input); } else { return $input }` for the callback but that didn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: @Anticom my solution below sorts that out.

Answer (score 13):

It says in the [`json_encode()` documentation](http://php.net/json_encode):

> This function only works with UTF-8 encoded data.

You should convert it to utf-8 with [iconv](http://php.net/iconv) or [mbstring](http://php.net/mbstring) first.

Answer (score 6):

This function will cast the correct data type for the JSON output and utf8_encode the strings.

```
/**
 * Change data-type from string to integar or float if required.
 * If string detected then utf8_encode() it.
 */
function cast_data_types ($value) {
  if (is_array($value)) {
    return array_map('cast_data_types',$value);
  }
  if (is_numeric($value)) {
    if(strpos('.', $value)===false) return (float)$value;
    return (int)$value;
  }
  return mb_convert_encoding((string)$value, 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1');
}

json_encode (cast_data_types($data));
```

Comment: Worked in my case. Thanks.

Comment: This worked for me too, just don't forget to change utf8_encode which is not supported anymore.
in my case I just changed to: mb_convert_encoding((string)$value,'UTF-8')

Answer (score 2):

JSON defines strings as Unicode!

[JSON Definition](http://json.org/)

You have to encode you ISO to UTF-8

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but figured I'd put this here in case someone needs to log data using json_encode but keep the data untouched, intact for inspection later.

You can encode the data raw using `base64_encode`, then it will work with `json_encode`. Later after running `json_decode`, you can decode the string with `base64_decode`, you'll get the original data unmodified.

Answer (score 1):

As of PHP 5.4.0:

Convert your strings in your array to into `utf-8` using `utf8_encode($str)` function.

Then `json_encode` with **JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE** option:

`$arr = json_encode($array, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);`

Answer (score 0):

Using the standard method when reading from MySQL:

```
$resultArray = array();
while($obj = MySQL_fetch_object($res)) {
 $resultArray[] = $obj;
}
$result = json_encode($resultArray);
```

The encoding can be done using the following:

```
$resultArray = array();
while($obj = MySQL_fetch_object($res)) {
 foreach($obj as $key => $value) {
  if (!is_null($value)) {
   $obj->$key = utf8_encode($value);
  }
 }
 $resultArray[] = $obj;
}
$result = json_encode($resultArray);
```

The `if is_null` has to be included so that null fields (e.g., DateTime fields) remain null in the output.

Answer (score 0):

The `$data` (in my case) is an array with text values as **ISO-8859-1**. The trick below prepares `$data` to be used with `json_encode`.

```
function toUtf8(&$v, $k) {
    $v = utf8_encode($v);
}
array_walk_recursive($data, 'toUtf8');
```