# Empty json_encode

Tags: php, mysql, json, crud

below PHP code. It makes a query on the database, puts the data into an array , and then try to pass it to json and print these same data.

The problem is that the print is coming out empty.
Using `print_r` I can print the data from the array, but when I pass the data to json , the return is null. How can I fix this?

```
<?php        
    $user = "root";
    $password = "";
    $db = "angulardb";
    $host = "localhost";
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", $user, $password, $db);

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $usuario = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT *  FROM users");

    if (!$usuario) {
        echo "Não foi possível executar a consulta no banco de dados: " . mysql_error();
        exit;

    }

    $return = array();

    while ($dados = mysqli_fetch_assoc($usuario)) {
        $return[] = $dados;

    }
    header('Content-Type: application/json');   
    echo json_encode($return);

?>
```

**Database:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `pass` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `nome`, `email`, `pass`) VALUES
(2, 'João Silva', 'joao.silva@angular.com', '123456'),
(3, 'Mario de Almeida', 'mario.almeida@angular.com', '123456');
```

Comment: Perhaps try json_last_error: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Apparently the error was in the collation of the database . The bank was like latin, moved to utf8 and functioned normally . thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the fact, that data returned from the database might contain some non-utf-8 character.

You can try with this :

```
json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)
```

OR

```
json_decode($json, false, 512, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)
```

Also try out this answer in this link :
[How to get json_encode() to work with ISO-8859-1 (åäö)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394305/how-to-get-json-encode-to-work-with-iso-8859-1-%C3%A5%C3%A4%C3%B6)