# Convert PHP array to JS array (ISO 8859-1 characters)

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I can't get it to work despite all the sources. I try the following :

```
<?php
$list_array = array();
foreach ($this->resultatTypeMail as $mailType) {
    $nom          = $mailType->getNom();
    $objet        = $mailType->getObjet();
    $list_array[] = array(
        'Name'   => $nom,
        'Object' => $objet,
    );
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$nom');</script>"; // this is OK
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$objet');</script>"; // this is OK
}
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var js_array = [<?php echo json_encode( $list_array ); ?>];
 alert(js_array[0]); // This returns undefined
</script>
```

I get satisfying results on `$nom` and `$objet` when I alert them.

**Problem :**
`js_array[0]` returns `undefined`

Note that I'm not in UTF-8. I'm not sure it's relevant though.

EDIT : A big picture of my goal is to get an array of custom php objet to be usable in JS.

Comment: replace  var js_array = [<?php echo json_encode( $list_array ) ?>];
with  var js_array = [<?php echo json_encode( $list_array ); ?>];
and check

Comment: I believe json_encode encodes arrays that have string values as array keys to JSON objects, rather than arrays.

Comment: @rahul_m good point but still the same error 'undefined'

Comment: have you tried it using console.log(js_array[0]); ?

Comment: I've checked my previous comment and it's true. Your solution is to use array_values, so it's properly converted to an array. Alternatively in your javascript use js_array.Name

Comment: I get 'undefined' also with : console.log(js_array[0]);

Comment: @JensKooij Let me try this

Comment: close php before <script> after foreach

Comment: @vSugumar thanks. Problem remains but good point

Comment: print_r($list_array) see the results after foreach

Comment: I get this output : Array ( [0] => Array ( [Name] => //Complétion [Object] => Veuillez compléter votre profil ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [Name] => //Complétion [Object] => Veuillez compléter votre profil ) [1] => Array ( [Name] => //Complétion [Object] => Veuillez compléter votre profil 2 ) ) ----- in which appear my db values

Comment: According to all answers I'm really starting to think it has to do with encoding

Comment: can you check the page source and see what the `json_encode` is actually printing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the [] from `var js_array =` line and it will work:

**wrong**:

```
var js_array = [<?php echo json_encode( array_values($list_array) ); ?>];
```

**right**:

```
var js_array = <?php echo json_encode( array_values($list_array) ); ?>;
```

Working code:

```
<?php

class MailType {
   function __construct($n, $o) {
       $this->nom = $n;
       $this->objet = $o;
   }

    private $nom;
    private $objet;

    public function getNom() {
        return $this->nom;
    }

    public function getObjet() {
        return $this->objet;
    }

}

$list_array = array();
$resultatTypeMail = array(new MailType('John', 'obj1'), new MailType('Mary', 'obj2'));
foreach ($resultatTypeMail as $mailType) {
    $nom          = $mailType->getNom();
    $objet        = $mailType->getObjet();
    $list_array[] = array(
        'Name'   => $nom,
        'Object' => $objet,
    );
    //echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$nom');</script>"; // this is OK
    //echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$objet');</script>"; // this is OK
}
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var js_array = <?php echo json_encode( $list_array ) ?>;
 alert(js_array[0].Name); // This returns John
</script>
```

You can see it running here: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/5xei-ybpn

(press F9 or click on 'Run - F9' to Run)

Comment: I said that in my answer and doesn't seem to work for the OP... Also the `[ ]` are not _wrong_ and the `alert` should work anyway with them...

Comment: @MikO sorry my former comment, I mixed up the answers.

Comment: Your code works, I confirm. I'll try switching it to my need to see what's happening and I'll report it here.

Comment: I marked your answer as accepted even though I believe all of them are right, and answer my original question. Turns out you guys couldn't solve my problem as my array was not fetch properly, but your answers lead me to the real problem. Thank you all !

Comment: Could you share with us, what the real problem was ?

Answer (score 1):

In PHP an array that has string keys gets converted to an object when parsed with json_encode.

You could either use array_keys to force the creation of an array, or use the object notation in your javascript

```
<?php
$list_array = array();
foreach ($this->resultatTypeMail as $mailType) {
    $nom          = $mailType->getNom();
    $objet        = $mailType->getObjet();
    $list_array[] = array(
        'Name'   => $nom,
        'Object' => $objet,
    );
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$nom');</script>"; // this is OK
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$objet');</script>"; // this is OK
}
<script type="text/javascript">
 var js_array = [<?php echo json_encode( array_values($list_array) ); ?>];
 alert(js_array[0]); 
</script>
```

Or

```
<?php
$list_array = array();
foreach ($this->resultatTypeMail as $mailType) {
    $nom          = $mailType->getNom();
    $objet        = $mailType->getObjet();
    $list_array[] = array(
        'Name'   => $nom,
        'Object' => $objet,
    );
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$nom');</script>"; // this is OK
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$objet');</script>"; // this is OK
}
<script type="text/javascript">
 var js_array = [<?php echo json_encode( array_values($list_array) ); ?>];
 alert(js_array.Name); 
</script>
```

Comment: since the OP has surrounded the JSON with brackets `[ ]`, the result should be an array containing only 1 item with the whole JSON string in it, which may not be what the OP wants, but `alert(js_array[0])` should work without the need of `array_values` or anything... I don't think this is the solution...

Comment: I still get 'undefined' with both solutions :/

Comment: I tested your code here and you have 3 errors: you forgot the closing ?> tag in both versions and the 2nd version still alerts undefined.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have multiple issues: you're missing the `;` after the `json_encode()` line (which is not actually required); you're surrounding the result of `json_encode()` with brackets (which should work but I expect it's not what you want); and the most important, you're missing the closing PHP `?>` tag before printing the JS...

This works for me:

```
<?php
    // your PHP code here...
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
   var js_array = <?php echo json_encode($list_array); ?>;
   alert(js_array[0]); // This works for me!
</script>
```

---

It looks like the issue may be in the encoding as you say - it seems that `json_encode` only works with UTF-8! From the [`json_encode()` docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php):

> All string data must be UTF-8 encoded.

So I think you'll have to convert your strings to UTF-8 before putting them into the array, something like:

```
$list_array[] = array(
    'Name'   => utf8_encode($nom),
    'Object' => utf8_encode($objet),
);
```

I *think* just that should work - otherwise you can try [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php#112020) from the comments in the same `json_encode()` docs; or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394305/how-to-get-json-encode-to-work-with-iso-8859-1-%C3%A5%C3%A4%C3%B6) other question to get more ideas...

Comment: before ?> ; is optional

Comment: I edited according to your wise points, but still 'undefined' for me

Comment: true! it's been so long since I don't work in a plain PHP script that I can't remember last time I used a closing tag anyway :)

Comment: Man it really has to be an issue with encoding. I'm using iso 8859-1, I'll try to see if switching to UTF 8 solves my problem... Would be a problematic though.